# TFS2015 - Error at the very end of a build - An error occurred while copying diagnostic activity logs to the drop location

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I have taken my production `TFS 2015` databases and restored in a test server with another installation of `TFS 2015` on it. The production `TFS 2015` works fine.

Now all my build jobs in this test environment (they are not the default xaml, I have added a message at the end of my workflow, and the message gets displayed, so I am thinking my xaml is not the cause here) end with the message bellow:

> An error occurred while copying diagnostic activity logs to the drop
>   location. **Details: No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an
>   object of type 'IEnumerable`1' from content with media type
>   'text/html'.**

The error above can be found on google, but the detail differs. I was able to find the detail in other context, as in ASP.NET development.

I have also given full access to the build controller user over the build machine. So it does not seem to be a authentication issues.

I have already tried removing all the build agents, the controllers and adding back again. That did not fix the issue.

Has anyone else run into this? Or has any idea what to try next?

Comment: Does the test server have the same hardware environment as the production server? If you create a new build with the default build process template(not the custom template), will you be able to reproduce this issue? Also, check Event Log to see whether you can get more error message.

Comment: +Cece this server worked for TFS 2012, TFS 2015 started doing this. Both servers are virtual machines. So the hardware should not matter in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In order to narrow down the issue, you may try to:

1. Check the workspace mappings in your Build Definition to see whether it points to correct workspace.
2. Check the drop location in the build definition to see whether you can access it on the build agent machine.
3. Check whether you can find the solution in C:\Builds folder on your build agent machine.

Comment: 1. I am using XAML builds, not sure where to check the workspace mapping. The account that is running as the build agent has a workspace, but TFS does not drop it there. 2. Yes, the directory is on the same box and has the access required. I even gave everyone full rights to the directory just in case. 3. Yes, the solution is there, the msbuild actually finishes and I even have my dlls there, but at the very end of the build if fails and gives me the "partial completed" status.

Comment: The workspace mapping here means the Source Settings in xaml Build Definition. Did you try to create a new build definition with the default build process template? How's the result?

Comment: Just tried the default Build Definition 'DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml' and I get the exact same error at the very end of the build. What is bugging me is the detail text: **No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'IEnumerable`1' from content with media type 'text/html'.** Do I need to install any software that my production has, but my test environment does not?

Comment: Other things that I have tried and did NOT work: - Uninstalled TFS 2015 and installed on a different directory. Deleted the contents of the IIS folder for TFS Web UI. Removed the **Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redsitributable** and installed the latest version of x86 and x64. Installed TFS 2015 back in, configured with the same database. Right now I am trying a repair on Visual Studio 2015. I am pretty sure this issue is related to the server, but not sure what yet.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after trying this backward and forwards I found a solution is not the best solution, but it seems to work. Also not sure why this is.

I removed all the Build Agents and Build Controllers. I also Unregistered the Build Service.

I went to Visual Studio -> Team Explorer -> Builds -> Actions -> Manage Build Controllers.
I then removed all the items found on the Manage Build Controllers screen.

I then went back to "XAML Build Configuration" on ***Team Foundation Server Administration Console*** and Re-added the Build Service, Controllers and Agents. Big note here ***I had to choose different names*** I renamed all my Controllers and Agents to different names. Not sure why, but this was the reason why it was not working before. I had tried this whole removal and re-adding, but adding with the same names did not fix the issue.

Hope this helps someone else.